# Fitting a /21 and 8 X /24 networks within a /20

Tags: networking, subnet

A /20 network can contain 16 /24 networks.  Would it be possible to split the first half of the network into a /21 and put the second half into 8 /24 networks?  If yes, is this fairly common?

Comment: Yes it can, but what is your definition of common?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean 'can I take my contiguous `/20` range and split it into one `/21` and eight `/24`s?', then the answer is 'yes, you can slice and dice it however you want'.

There's plenty of work involved in configuring all the hosts with their new netmasks, and making sure you get the routing right between the subnets (and to the rest of the world), but there's no theoretical reason why you shouldn't do this.

When you ask 'is this fairly common?', plenty of large organisations have, say, a `/16` which they've split up into many subnets of varying sizes as required.  So in short: yes, it's very common.